# pgfplot, placing 3 graphs next to each other in one coordinate system with different headers

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create this graph:

[image]

The graph is from a scientific paper which I want to quote in my master thesis. As it looks nicer if I create the graph myself than inserting it as a picture, I need your help

I don't know how to separate the graphs like in the picture and give them different headers.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
width=\textwidth,
bar width=6mm,
ylabel={Conservation impact (\%)},
symbolic x coords={Newfoundland Power, Hydro One TOU 1, Hydro One RTM, BC Hydro, Woodstock Hydro, SRP, Country Energy, Hydro One TOU 2},
xtick =data,
x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
]
\addplot coordinates {(Newfoundland Power, 18) (Hydro One TOU 1, 6.8)(Hydro One RTM, 6.4)(BC Hydro, 2.8)(Woodstock Hydro, 15)(SRP, 12.9)(Country Energy, 8)(Hydro One TOU 2, 6.8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{120,211,255}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar,
  width=1.6\textwidth,
  height=13cm,
  bar width=12mm,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style={dashed,help lines,gray!50},
  ylabel={Conservation impact (\%)},
  symbolic x coords={Newfoundland Power, Hydro One TOU 1, Hydro One RTM, BC Hydro, , Woodstock Hydro, SRP, , Country Energy, Hydro One TOU 2},
  xtick =data,
  x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
]
\addplot[fill=barblue] coordinates {(Newfoundland Power, 18) (Hydro One TOU 1, 6.8)(Hydro One RTM, 6.4)(BC Hydro, 2.8)(Woodstock Hydro, 15)(SRP, 12.9)(Country Energy, 8)(Hydro One TOU 2, 6.8)};
\draw[help lines,gray!50] 
  ( $ (axis cs:BC Hydro,0)!0.5!(axis cs:Woodstock Hydro,0) $ ) -- 
  ( $ (axis cs:BC Hydro,20)!0.5!(axis cs:Woodstock Hydro,20) $ );
\draw[help lines,gray!50] 
  ( $ (axis cs:SRP,0)!0.5!(axis cs:Country Energy,0) $ ) -- 
  ( $ (axis cs:SRP,20)!0.5!(axis cs:Country Energy,20) $ );
\node[anchor=north,yshift=-10pt,text=red] at
  ( $ (axis cs:Hydro One TOU 1,20)!0.5!(axis cs:Hydro One RTM,20) $ ) 
  {IHD-Only Impacts};  
\node[anchor=north,yshift=-10pt,text=red,align=center] at
  ( $ (axis cs:Woodstock Hydro,20)!0.5!(axis cs:SRP,20) $ ) 
  {IHD and Prepayment \\ Impacts};  
\node[anchor=north,yshift=-10pt,text=red,align=center] at
  ( $ (axis cs:Country Energy,20)!0.5!(axis cs:Hydro One TOU 2,20) $ ) 
  {IHD and Time-Varying Rates \\ Impacts};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```